# are two anagram or not?

Tags: java, string, anagram

My question is that in this code, initially we have taken boolean **isAnagram** false, and then set the condition, but we are getting wrong result. As it is clearly understood that they are not anagram but code output is 'anagram' .

```
package strings;

public class Anagrams {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String a = "aab";
        String b = "abc";
        
        boolean isAnagram = false;
        
        int al[] = new int[256];
        int bl[] = new int[256];
        
        for(char c:a.toCharArray()) {
            int index = (int)c;
            al[index]++;
            }
        for(char c:b.toCharArray()) {
            int index = (int)c;
            bl[index]++;
            }
        
        for(int i = 0; i<256; i++) {
            if(al[i] == bl[i]) {
                isAnagram = true;
            }
        }
        
        if(isAnagram) {
            System.out.println("anagram");
        }else {
            System.out.println("not anagram");
        }
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is within the last `for`-loop. We have to iterate over both arrays `a` and `b` in total to decide whether the words are anagrams of each other. Thus, I recommend to start with the hypothesis that they are anagrams (`boolean isAnagram = true`), iterate over `a` and `b` and set `isAnagram` to `false` iff. `a[i] != b[i]` (we can also berak the loop if we found a mismatch). I also recommend reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: A remark: `char`s in java are actually encoded in unicode. So the `int`-value of a `char` could be `>= 256` ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/4YP9IA)). Admitted, this might be a corner case. But using a `Map<Character, Integer>` instead of an `int[256]` to keep track of character occurences can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think sorting the string and then compare them is more simple.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "aab";
    String b = "abc";

    char[] a1 = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] b1 = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(a1);
    Arrays.sort(b1);
    
    boolean isAnagram = new String(a1).equals(new String(b1));

    System.out.println(isAnagram ? "anagram" : "not anagram");
}
```

Comment: though you have a point, it doesn't actually explain the problem the OP has.

Comment: @Stultuske You're right ;-) But I answer the question in the title.

Comment: Furthermore, sorting has in general a higher time complexity (`O(n log(n))` than linear scanning.

Comment: @Turing85 You emphasize the importance of optimizations. I would myself upvote your answer if the questioner asked for them. I didn't downvote them here. Regards.

Comment: @bimjhi no, not really. I am just pointing it out since the original solution has linear time complexity. My answer has a worst-case time complelxity of `O(n log(n))` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.

The questioner wants his own algorithm to work.
The main bug is that it needs to find mismatches in the char set for two words being compared.

So you can declare a counter and while you iterate through char position in both words you increase the counter every time you find a mismatch between the number of some specific letter in the first and the second word.

At the end, if the counter > 0, this means the words have different sets of chars.

The working code:

```
class Ideone
{
// Online Java Compiler
// Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online


public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String a = "aab";
        String b = "abb";
        int mismatch = 0;
        
        boolean isAnagram = true;
        
        int al[] = new int[143859];
        int bl[] = new int[143859];
        
        for(char c:a.toCharArray()) {
            int index = (int)c;
            al[index]++;
            }
        for(char c:b.toCharArray()) {
            int index = (int)c;
            bl[index]++;
            }
        
        for(int i = 0; i<143859; i++) {
            if(al[i] != bl[i]) {
                mismatch++;
            }
        }
        
        if (mismatch>0) isAnagram = false;
        
        if(isAnagram) {
            System.out.println("anagram");
        }else {
            System.out.println("not anagram");
        }
    
        }

}
```

Comment: 143859 is the number of Unicode char in the current standard version.

Comment: Why not break if `al[i] != bl[i]`?

Comment: It's better for human readability. You see the code looks for a mismatch and understand why you get isAnagram = false at the end. I don't deny your advocating optimizations.

Comment: That's debatable. In my opinion, your algorithm calculates something that it does not need to calculate (i.e. the number of mismatches).

Answer (score 0):

Your code yields `true` if ONE char count matches. But it should only be `true` if ALL char counts match. Turn the logic around, start with `true` and set to `false` on the first mismatch. Change the line

```
boolean isAnagram = false;
```

to

```
boolean isAnagram = true;
```

and

```
if(al[i] == bl[i]) {
    isAnagram = true;
}
```

to

```
if(al[i] != bl[i]) {
    isAnagram = false;
    break;
}
```

But sorting the strings is indeed the solution that is more readable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the last `for`-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<256; i++) {
    if(al[i] == bl[i]) {
        isAnagram = true;
    }
}
```

If only a single position in both arrays match, `isAnagram` is set to `true`. To fix the problem, We can inverse our perspective: Let us assume that the two `String`s are anagrams at the start (`boolean isAnagram = true;`) and set the flag to `false` iff. the two arrays `a` and `b` differ on some index `i`. We can also break the loop on the first mismatch we find.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String a = "aab";
  String b = "aac";

  boolean isAnagram = true;

  int al[] = new int[256];
  int bl[] = new int[256];

  for (char c : a.toCharArray()) {
    int index = (int) c;
    al[index]++;
  }
  for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
    int index = (int) c;
    bl[index]++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (al[i] != bl[i]) {
      isAnagram = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isAnagram) {
    System.out.println("anagram");
  } else {
    System.out.println("not anagram");
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YesAD5)

Since `char`s in Java are encoded in unicode, it could occur that the `int`-value of a `char` is `>= 256` ([<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4YP9IA)). To prevent this problem, we can use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to keep track of the codepoint frequency:

```
public static boolean areAnagrams(String s, String t) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(s, "Parameter \"s\" is null");
  Objects.requireNonNull(t, "Parameter \"t\" is null");
  return Objects.equals(s, t) ||
      Objects.equals(getCodePointFrequency(s), getCodePointFrequency(t));
}

public static Map<Integer, Integer> getCodePointFrequency(String s) {
  return s.codePoints()
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), c -> 1, Integer::sum));
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sU3KbD)

It should be mentioned that this solution has a worst-case time complexity of `O(n log(n))` since an insert into a map only guarantees `O(log(n))`, not `O(1)`. The average case, however, should be `O(max(n))`, with `n` being the length of the longer `String` of `s` and `t`.

Comment: Why not just replace 256 with 150k?

Comment: Counter-question: Why should I allocate more memory than necessary?

Comment: We should optimize code for human readability first, and only optimize for the machine when the cost of performance to the users outweighs the cost of a clean design to the readers of the code. (Robert C. Martin)

Comment: ant an `int[]` (with two implicit mappings) is more readable than a `Map<Character, Integer>` (with one explicit mapping)?

Comment: One may object that the solution with Map<Character, Integer> is platform-specific. Say, a C# developer has to look into Oracle's documentation for Collectors class description.

Comment: You are mixing up platform- with language-specific. Java is platform-independent (as long as a JCK-compatible JRE exists for the platform, of course). The question is clearly tagged with `java`, not with `C#` (otherwise I would not have answered it). I do not see the point of your comment.